# Venice hotels - is the city centre ok for visiting the tourist part?

Tags: venice

I looked at the map and I am just confused. If I reserve a hotel in Via Montello, 8, 30171 Venezia VE can I easily go to C8QP+59 Venice, Metropolitan City of Venice, Italy? How should we go? It seems that the city center itself is somehow different from the touristic part?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "C8QP+59". The address you however mention is on the mainland, not on the Island.

Comment: `C8QP+59 Venice, Metropolitan City of Venice, Italy` equals `45.437938,12.335938`

Answer (score 8):

Venice consists of two parts. The old city in the laguna and the modern city on the mainland. Most people nowadays live on the mainland (Mestre as it's called).

Your selected hotel is very close to Mestre station where you should be able to catch multiple trains per hour towards Santa Lucia station in the old city. Will take a couple of minutes only. So it's an OK option for staying in Venice.

Comment: Ok. Great. So, There is train to old city which is more beautiful right? I mean the old city is well-known right? How is the weather at the end of september generally?

Comment: Yes, you usually don't visit the modern city. Everything you know as Venice is in the laguna. I guess end of September is a very good time to travel. Not too hot or overly touristy like in summer and canals won't smell anymore. Of course there can always be rain.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think we can go morning soon from milan by bus or train to Venice and visit Venice and turn back night or not ?

Comment: Train is the only option for a day trip but Venice is definitely worth a couple of days. So, yes, a day trip from Milan is doable.